# Unbiased estimation of the bispectrum

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

There are many methods of computing estimations of the bispectrum, and in particular regarding methods to give unbiased estimations of this quantity. I was wondering whether if, given a complex-valued signal $x_t$, one can obtain an unbiased estimate of the bispectrum $B(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ for any given $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ by considering an unbiased estimate of the spectrum of
$\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{\xi_1}\left[\hat{x}(\xi_1)\hat{x}(\xi_2)\overline{\hat{x}(\xi_1+\xi_2)} \right](t)$, where $\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{\xi_1}$ denotes the inverse DFT with respect to the variable $\xi_1$ and $\hat{x}(\xi)$ denotes the DFT of $x$.

My guess is that, given the large literature available on the subject, this approach is too naive, but I fail to see what actually goes wrong.